# Extension of protocols in Swift

Tags: swift, compilation, protocols

I want to do something like mixins, because of code repeation. Swift crashes on compile =( How can I solve it?

```
public protocol ExpandTabScrollDelegate: class {
    func tabScrollContent(_ content: ExpandTabScrollContent, didScroll offset: CGPoint)
}

public protocol ExpandTabScrollContent: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    var contentScroll: UIScrollView { get }
    var tabScrollDelegate: ExpandTabScrollDelegate? { get set }
}



public extension ExpandTabScrollContent {

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        tabScrollDelegate?.tabScrollContent(self, didScroll: scrollView.contentOffset)
    }
}
```

P.S> I handle all scroll view delegate method, here I simplified a code.

Compile error:

```
0  swift                    0x0000000111dca3ad PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 45
1  swift                    0x0000000111dc9b56 SignalHandler(int) + 790
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff8d26452a _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x0000000000000030 _sigtramp + 1926871840
4  swift                    0x000000010eea9239 swift::irgen::IRGenFunction::emitTypeMetadataRef(swift::CanType) + 73
5  swift                    0x000000010eef0317 void llvm::function_ref<void (swift::irgen::GenericRequirement)>::callback_fn<(anonymous namespace)::EmitPolymorphicArguments::emit(swift::CanTypeWrapper<swift::SILFunctionType>, llvm::ArrayRef<swift::Substitution>, swift::irgen::WitnessMetadata*, swift::irgen::Explosion&)::$_14>(long, swift::irgen::GenericRequirement) + 871
6  swift                    0x000000010eee5471 (anonymous namespace)::PolymorphicConvention::enumerateRequirements(llvm::function_ref<void (swift::irgen::GenericRequirement)> const&) + 129
7  swift                    0x000000010eeefe68 swift::irgen::emitPolymorphicArguments(swift::irgen::IRGenFunction&, swift::CanTypeWrapper<swift::SILFunctionType>, swift::CanTypeWrapper<swift::SILFunctionType>, llvm::ArrayRef<swift::Substitution>, swift::irgen::WitnessMetadata*, swift::irgen::Explosion&) + 472
8  swift                    0x000000010ef52e71 (anonymous namespace)::IRGenSILFunction::visitFullApplySite(swift::FullApplySite) + 2929
9  swift                    0x000000010ef3d458 swift::irgen::IRGenModule::emitSILFunction(swift::SILFunction*) + 9160
10 swift                    0x000000010ee4cea1 swift::irgen::IRGenerator::emitGlobalTopLevel() + 1521
11 swift                    0x000000010ef2235f performIRGeneration(swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SILModule*, llvm::StringRef, llvm::LLVMContext&, swift::SourceFile*, unsigned int) + 1247
12 swift                    0x000000010edd7f31 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 23777
13 swift                    0x000000010edd02b3 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 17859
14 swift                    0x000000010ed8c5cf main + 8239
15 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff9542d5ad start + 1
16 libdyld.dylib            0x0000000000000040 start + 1790782100
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: [lot of text]
1.  While emitting IR SIL function @_TToFE7Test123PS_22ExpandTabScrollContent19scrollViewDidScrollfCSo12UIScrollViewT_ for 'scrollViewDidScroll' at /Users/Alexandr/Documents/test_projects/Test123/Test123/ViewController.swift:24:5
```

Comment: Can you please include the compiler error messages?

Comment: @Alladinian done